# Clear checklist in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checklistbox

I am trying to write code for my reset button in vb. I have used the following:

```
chlstAddIn.ClearSelected();
```

But it only clears the highlighting, not the checkbox itself.

Comment: Do you want the checked items to be unchecked  or the checked items itself to be removed from checklistbox ? Didn't get you quite well

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this. I need the checked items to be unchecked when btnReset is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select and Check are two different concepts in the checkedlistbox. **ClearSelected** will not uncheck the items. To uncheck all items that are checked, use **SetItemCheckState**. This is what i would do in c#.

```
foreach (int i in chlstAddIn.CheckedIndices)
{
chlstAddIn.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Unchecked);
}
```

In VB, use this code in reset button click event,

```
For Each i As Integer In chlstAddIn.CheckedIndices
  chlstAddIn.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Unchecked)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your help it worked; I truly appreciate it! It's hard to be a newbie.

Comment: I feel you bro ! Please accept the answer  if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
 For Each i As Integer In CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices
            CheckedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Unchecked)
        Next
```

Comment: Hello john, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add some explanation for why your solution works to your answer?